# How to handle API's validation based on a flag

Tags: api-design

I have the following case:

- If the user is in the UK, the server needs to validate the bank details as Account number and Sort code number
- If the user is in France, the server needs to validate the bank details as IBAN and BIC numbers

So how would you design the API for this?

One idea is to add as part of the payload every option and a flag
e.g.

```
{
  "iban": string,
  "bic": string,
  "accountNumber": number,
  "sortCode": string,
  "country": "UK"
}
```

In the validation function I would then write the code along the line of this pseudo code

```
if country is France
   throw error if accountNumber and sortCode are present
   throw error if iban and bic are not valid
   continue flow
if country is UK
   throw error if iban and bic are present
   throw error if accountNumber and sortCode are not valid
   continue flow
```

Any thoughts on this or any better approaches following best practises?

Thank you for your opinion

Comment: What does "I am in the UK" mean? Who or what exactly does "I" refer to?

Comment: read the rest of the question

Comment: I read the whole question. But it wasn't clear whether "I" means the organisation running the server, or the authenticated user, or the owner of the bank account, or the bank account itself, or something else. I think the answer could be different depending what it means.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for clarifying, I updated the question with clearer information.

Comment: how about something like `{"uk": {"accountNumber": string, "sortCode": string}, "fr": {"iban": string, "bic": string}}`. At least I would probably not allow mixed bank info properties in a single bank account object. Maybe instead of keys "uk" and "fr" use "ibanBankAccount" and however that is called for uk.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker, that is interesting actually, but how about when other countries will be added (and it's going to happen for a given)? So for instance Italy and Belgium also require Iban and bic, that means I would have a bigger object in that regard? What are your thoughts?

Comment: The you might use `{"whatever-that-in-the-uk-is-called": {"accountNumber": string, "sortCode": string}, "ibanBankAccount": {"iban": string, "bic": string}}` and for other countries also using iban you would reuse `ibanBankAccount`. And if there is coming in another option then just add `"this-other-option"` besides `"ibanBankAccount"`.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you for your opinion, it really makes sense!

Comment: Shouldn't it be the country where the bank account is located? I mean, me as a user can have different bank account in different countries?

Comment: you can make an abstract class where you define all logical method and inheriti this class for individual counmtiry and add criteria for each country there. then have a dictionary which map the country code to class and then add all logic of bank related stuff there related to thatr country. with this way if any of country criteria changes then you can easily modify that

Answer (score 1):

What you're dealing with is conditional validation, and there is no one-size-fits-all answer here. The complexity of your API contract very much hinges on the complexity of your conditions and how distinct your possible data options are.

For example, if in both cases you'd be using a string value, and you'd simply be validating this string value differently, I'd reuse the same `AccountNumber` string property and just vary the validation rules.

If you're dealing with a bigger difference between the two options, you have to consider tradeoffs here. Do you want your API to be able to account for other countries (added in the future) without breaking the contract? Or are you okay breaking/changing the contract as needed?

That's the end of the generalized answer. There is no one-size-fits all answer here.

---

Now let's discuss your particular case.

**Question 1** - why even bother tracking the country in that object? Clearly, which fields are filled in already tells you which kind of account number validation you need.

You could simplify your code to not test for country, only for account details. Very rough pseudocode:

```
int validationsDone = 0

if iban and bic are not empty
    validate iban and bic
    validationsDone + 1

if sortcode and accountnumber are not empty
    validate sortcode and accountnumber
    validationsDone + 1

if validationsDone != 1
    data is either missing or duplicate - cannot continue

validation succeeded
```

**Question 2** - Why are UK nationals prohibited from using IBAN numbers? What if they have an international account, or if they only know the IBAN details to their account?

It sounds to me like you're dealing with a bad labeling here. The split isn't inherently between countries, it's between types of bank account details. Don't add confusion by using different labels than what's being represented.

That being said, maybe your UI is shaped in a way that toggling the country changes the bank account detail input controls. That's perfectly fine, I'm not going to argue how you should build your UI, but just because your UI makes that country distinction does not mean that your API should as well.

> So for instance Italy and Belgium also require Iban and bic, that means I would have a bigger object in that regard?

See, this is exactly why I raised this point. Why would you need to add different fields when dealing with countries that use the *identical* IBAN format. There's no need to distinguish here, but your chosen format somehow forces you to need to so do anyway. That's indicative of bad design (or not mentioning the necessary justification for why the design needs this to happen this way).

**Question 3** - How are you storing the validated data?

- If you're storing them separately, then it doesn't make sense to reuse the same fields in your API. Storing them separately implies that you cannot find a way to store them with a reusable format, which disables the entire notion of reusing properties in your API.
- If they get stored in the same fields eventually, why bother starting off by using different fields to begin with? Clearly, both cases can be represented using a reusable format, so why aren't you using this reusable format in your API?

*Be very careful here: I'm not saying you have to expose your entities via your API. I'm saying that both your entities and API models can be structured similarly. If one is able to contain a reusable format, the other presumably can do it too. If one is incapable of containing a reusable format, the other is probably can't do it either.*

Answer (score 0):

> Any thoughts on this or any better approaches following best practices?

**I**nternational **B**ank **A**ccount **N**umbers are not magic numbers. Fortunately, they have a [format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#IBAN_formats_by_country)

```
France: FRBB BOOOO OCCC CCCC CCCC DD
UK: GBKK BBBB SSSS SSCC CCCC CC
```

So the payload could be

```js
{ "iban": "FRBB BOOOO OCCC CCCC CCCC DD" } //France
{ "iban": "GBKK BBBB SSSS SSCC CCCC CC" } //UK
```

Once on the server, the `payload.iban.substring(0,2)` tells you the country code. Once you have the country, you could ask for a validator

```js
const ibanValidator = ibanValidatorProvider(countryCode).get();
```

And validate

```js
const isValidIban = ibanValidator.validate(payload.iban);
```

Validators can be a hierarchy of classes or a list of functions, each of which validates the IBAN of a concrete country (`UKIBANValidator`, `FranceIBANValidator`, etc).

Or, a single one implementing the validation algorithm. Preferably a single one sending a request to [IBAN Check API](https://www.iban.com/developers)

If you know the country and the corresponding format, you can get each code (bic, sortCode, accountNumber) by [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656264/iban-regex-design).

---

Comment: You're changing the criteria. Sometimes, IBAN is not used when not dealing with an international entity (i.e. you, the user and their bank account are in the same country and there's a non-IBAN way to refer to the bank account), and that seems to be the case for the OP. You cannot just mandate that OP ignores the non-IBAN format, we should assume it is part of the acceptance criteria.

Comment: The non-IBAN format is also structured. The input still can be a single string and we can know which format is send by reg expressions. Once know the format, we can apply concrete validations.

Comment: BTW, domestic account number can be found as the BBAN (within and IBAN). The same rules validating the BBAN of an IBAN can be applied to validate non IBAN numbers.

Answer (score -2):

This is a business logic concern.  [image: “clean architecture”]

In a typical "clean architecture" it would belong in the application layer.

Your API receives a request, it forwards the request to an application layer, the application layer responds by a result object that contains either success of failure. If failure, then you would include in your response object a list of validation messages. If success, then you would include in your response the result of your operation.

Comment: Hi Philip, thanks but I don't think that gives an opinion on the actual payload structure and validation

Comment: You did not read the question. The question is not about which layer the validation should occur on.